# Dynamically selecting one data series for Excel chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have this data table.

[image: Trend Data Range]

From this I want to draw a chart where Year and Week are the X-Axis. On that chart I will select one of the columns to plot as the data series (line chart). I want the plot to be dynamic where I can tell it to plot a line for Filler or Labeler or Pasteurizer.  So I want to be able to tell the chart which column it should plot: G or H or K, or any of the columns in the data range.

I know how to retrieve one value with INDEX and SUMPRODUCT. But is there a way to retrieve an entire column based on the value in row 3?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a dynamic range name. For example, if you plot rows 4 to 15, then you can build a dynamic range called "mySeries" for the series with this formula

```
=OFFSET(Sheet!$A$4:$A$15,0,MATCH("Filler",Sheet!$4:$4,0)-1)
```

Instead of "Filler" as a constant, use a cell reference. The rows can be made dynamic, too, by using a dynamic range based on other formulas.

Plug the series into the chart source using the sheet name in front of the series name.

```
=Sheet!mySeries
```

Comment: The problem is that I must build the sheet name. It changes based on a the selection from a combo box.

Comment: You can make the sheet name dynamic, too. If you care to post your FULL requirements, instead of just saying "but" after a suggestion, it would be easier to give you the best solution first time.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the way to do this was to build the table on the side with INDIRECT formulas based on the machine selected.

[image]

Comment: Indirect is volatile and may slow down your workbook. Also, with the dynamic range you don't need to duplicate the data in order to plot it. The range formula will find the data where it already lives.